# Implementing Limit query in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

For my requirement i have to implement upper and lower limit in hive. For that i am trying to write query something like this

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 0, 5 
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 5, 5
```

But hive supports only 1 limit, it's not supporting upper and lower limit. I tried with with other alternatives to achieve this by using RANK(), ROWNUM() but didn't succeeded.

Can anyone please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might have to do this with rank() methods. Can you put more details on your data structure in hive and also the use case? Also, What is the version of hive you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the Facebook UDF and rownum functionality

Download the Facbook UDF's from GITHUB
https://github.com/brndnmtthws/facebook-hive-udfs

Create a jar file from the the UDF project

You can add the jar file from the local path in the hive console.

```
ADD JAR s3n://obfuscated-path/assets/jars/facebook-udfs-1.0.jar;
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION NumberRows AS 'com.facebook.hive.udf.UDFNumberRows';

SELECT 
  A.product_id, 
  A.category, 
  A.product_name, 
  A.brand, 
  A.rank_score,
  CAST(NumberRows(A.category) as FLOAT), 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    product_id, 
    category, 
    product_name, 
    brand,
    A.rank_score
  FROM
    source_table
  DISTRIBUTE BY 
    category 
  SORT BY
    category, rank_score desc
  ) A ;
```

Some more reference
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1545

[How can I add row numbers for rows in PIG or HIVE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288578/how-can-i-add-row-numbers-for-rows-in-pig-or-hive)