# How could retrieve the specific row from HIVE table?

Tags: hive

I have table of 200 rows and 50 columns in a HIVE table.

I could write one Java program to read the input file data by increment line number, when the line counter reached 10th row for top , i could print 10th row of table.

Instead of writing Java program , is there any way to retrieve the 10th row from table using HIVE query?

Comment: I think the answer in this question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385105/implementing-limit-query-in-hive

Comment: Maybe manual sampling can help you. Study the docs here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Sampling

Comment: "10th row" based on which criteria? Any ORDER BY clause involved???? Because by default SQL gives **no guarantee** that two different queries will return the rows in the same order... same for HQL.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this :

> select * from (select * from tableName limit 10) as tb1 limit 1;

It should give you the 10th row.

PS : Checked on non-partitioned managed table